# A few the same form with diffrent entity field type in 1 form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Hello I have a form with

```
  ->add('workers', 'entity',  array(
                'class'=>'Surgery\WorkersBundle\Entity\Workers',
                'property'=>'profession',
                'query_builder'=> function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er)
                {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                              ->where('u.profession = ?1 ')
                              ->setParameter(1, 'P');
                }
```

And I want in my template three the same forms with different parameters (L and M) Can do something like this? Have I  create 3 different forms?

Answer (score 2):

Option a:

Pass the object type as a parameter on the form-type constructor and use it when you are building your form.

Option b (probably better):

Use inheritance extending a form that is more abstract to others that are more specific.